# Django Rest how to show list of comment which belongs only from related Blog and Author?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Assume Author Jhone write an  **Blog** which title is *"This blog written by author Jhone"* and Author Joe write an  **Blog** *"This blog written by author Joe"* . Jhone blog received 20 comments and Joe blog received 10 comments. When Jhone will be login his account he can only able to see comments those belongs from his blog post and same will be for Joe. Here I tried this query `Comment.objects.all().filter(blog__author=request.user.id)` but still now everyone can see each others blog comments from my api url.    here is my code:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def comment_api(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    if request.method == 'GET':    
        comment = Comment.objects.all().filter(blog__author=request.user.id)
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Comment
          fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
      comment = models.TextField()
       blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing author id. instead of this `Comment.objects.all().filter(blog__author=request.user.id)` it will be `Comment.objects.all().filter(blog__author_id=request.user.id)`